# Changing the text appearance in styles and themes for an Android app

Tags: java, android, text, android-theme, android-styles

I am writing an android app and I am wanting to alter the theme of my app.

I have managed to alter the background colour of the app by using a theme, but I am struggling to change the default text appearance.

This is my **styles.xml** resource file.

```
<resources>
    <style name="QTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/q_green</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/q_green</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/QText</item> 
    </style>

    <color name="q_green">#008000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

    <style name="QText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textFont">Verdana</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and just to check, this is an example of one of my **TextViews** I want to use the above style in my layout file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDevice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/device" 
/>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: You've just overrided the `TextAppearance.Medium` style in your theme(which will not modify the `TextView`). If you want to modify the `TextView` look then override the `textViewStyle` style attribute in your theme. Or you could apply your custom style using `android:textAppearance`

Comment: Thanks. I changed the item name to android.textViewStyle and that seemed to do the trick. It changed tehe text inside my spinners though, not just my text views. Is there a way to differentiate?

Comment: I'm not sure. If I'm not mistaken the `Spinner`'s `TextView` item has a different style(which still inherits from the `TextView` style), pointed by the `spinnerItemStyle` attribute in the theme. You may want to set that to `@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just for completeness, and full credit to Lusprog, this is now my resources file

```
<resources>
    <style name="QTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/q_green</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/q_green</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/QText</item> 
    </style>

    <color name="q_green">#008000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

    <style name="QText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also thanks to Padma Kumar for the font help.

Comment: What you have changed? other than android:typeface!

Comment: <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/QText</item>

Comment: hay can you tell me android:textViewStyle is this attribute is there in android?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, but if you meant is android:textViewStyle an attribute in android, yes it appears to be.

Comment: How can I set text background color within style? If I am setting it with android:background color it's not working, although BackgroundColorSpan works out.

Answer (score 3):

//remove this line from your styles
there is no attribute like this

```
<item name="android:textFont">Verdana</item>
```

//you can give typeface for changing font style

```
<item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
```

//for settting the styles

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDevice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="@style/QText"
    android:text="@string/device" 
/>
```

Comment: is there a way I can add the style to the theme so I don't have to set the style for every text

Comment: No you can't set font style thru xml. need to set typeface thru code.