# java.lang.RuntimeException: android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my XML file I dont know i am getting an error as

> ```
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.booking_xml:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.booking_xml:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.booking_xml:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView
> ```

I was trying to create nested layout in linear layout can someone please help why this error is coming I have also attached my xml file to have a look at it.
If I am commenting the first textview then error show onto next textview
I have taken reference from [Android nested linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080801/android-nested-linear-layout) but i am unable to solve the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
    android:background="@color/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="571dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="189dp"
            android:layout_height="121dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/right" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/pnr_no"
            android:textColor="@color/back"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phn"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />



    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@color/back"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="Book another \n ticket"
            android:textColor="@color/back"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_button"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your java class code, there is sth wrong in TextView inflating class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason for the InflateException error is the 5th line in your code

`android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"`

So remove that and your code will run just fine. I think that is the answer you were looking for

Now if you want to set a custom appearance to all textviews in your current layout you should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416867/11546258) in an SO post.

You can use something like

```
        <style name="QTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
            <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3</item>
        </style>
```

Note the parent theme.